# does querying mysql by using function takes more time to load?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if using function to query specific row from a table each time the function is being called will be less sufficient than just querying once by a normal mysql query.

here's a clearer picture of what I mean.

```
function userinfo($table, $row, $data, $where){
global $db;
$users_sql = $db->query("SELECT $row FROM $table WHERE $where = '$data'");
$users_row = $db->fetch_assoc($users_sql);
return $users_row[$row];
}

echo userinfo('users', 'firstname', $_SESSION['username'],'username');
echo userinfo('users', 'avatar', $_SESSION['username'],'username');
```

or just doing this without a function

```
$users_sql = $db->query("SELECT $row FROM $table WHERE $where = '$data'");
$users_row = $db->fetch_assoc($users_sql);
echo $users_row['firstname'];
echo $users_row['avatar'];
```

I'm guessing the second way will be better, but I just gotta double check.

Comment: The first one takes more time since it has to access to the database two times

Comment: On a side node, if you are using the query at several places, you _should_ wrap it in a function, this centralized approach makes it easier to handle changes in the future.

Comment: that's why I'm doing a function for it. cuz i'm using it in a bunch of places. however, I can still use the second one too. i just wanna know if using the function will be something less professional than using that other way?

Comment: Using well written functions is __more__ professional, because it avoids code duplication, and means that any changes to code (such as error handling in case the query you generate isn't valid, or where no rows are returned) can be handled in one place in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first to:

```
function userinfo($table, $row, $data, $where){
    global $db;
    $users_sql = $db->query("SELECT $row FROM $table WHERE $where = '$data'");
    $users_row = $db->fetch_assoc($users_sql);
    return $users_row;
}
$row = userinfo('users', 'firstname, avatar', $_SESSION['username'],'username');
echo $row['firstname'];
echo $row['avatar'];
```

will make it more meaningful and avoid an additional database query; but your second "without a function" equivalent isn't equivalent at all because you're assuming that $users_row will return both `firstname` and `avatar`, while your first example doesn't (unless you use the logic I've shown above)

Even more generic would be

```
function userinfo($table, $data, $where){
    global $db;
    $users_sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where = '$data'");
    $users_row = $db->fetch_assoc($users_sql);
    return $users_row;
}
$row = userinfo('users', $_SESSION['username'],'username');
echo $row['firstname'];
echo $row['avatar'];
```

But your approach to this isn't good; you really should be using prepared statements and bind variables; and building your queries accordingly